# Understanding Inheritance and functions with different signatures

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Say I have a base class and a derived class.

```
class Base {
 public:
  void A(int x, int y) {do something}
  void B() {
    A(x,y);
    do something;
  }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  void A() {do something else};
};

Derived derived1;
derived1.B();
```

The signatures of the functions are different, will the B call the derived A or the base A? Iif it will call the derived B, I guess it will dismiss the parameters?

what if the derived A needed different parameters rather than no parameters, would I have to copy B's entire code into the derived class just to change the way B calls A?

Answer (score 2):

A function's code is always evaluated in the context of the class in which it is defined. This includes determining which function each expression calls. So inside `Base::B()`, the call `A(x, y)` is translated by the compiler as a call to `Base::A`. Even if you later call `derived1.B()`, it will call `derived1 . Base::A` (pseudo-syntax).

The only thing which changes this slightly is virtual functions. However, even with them, the rules are similar. Overload resolution (which is basically the process of matching a function name & signature to a call expression) is done in the context of the class where the containing function is defined. If the resolution leads to a virtual function being selected, the virtual call mechanism will then be invoked at runtime to call the appropriate override *of that function.*

Let's consider this example:

```
struct Base {
  virtual void foo(int);
  virtual void bar() { foo(0.0); }
};

struct Derived : Base {
  virtual void foo(int);
  virtual void foo(double);
};

Derived d;
d.bar();
```

Even in this example, calling `d.bar()` will call `Derived::foo(int)`. That's because the call-to-signature matching was done in the context of `Base`, which only sees `foo(int)` and employs the implicit conversion from `double` to `int.`

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons force `Base::B` to call `Base::A` not `Derived::A`

- It's calling `A` with specific overload: `A(int, int)`
- `Base::A` and `Base::B` are not virtual, so it calls `Base::A`. The code is not polymorphic.

The simplest example to show a how a virtual method works is:

```
class Base {
public:
   virtual void A() {
      // do job #1
   }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
   virtual void A() {
      // do job #2
   }
};

// ...

Derived derived1;

Base *base = &derived1;

base->A(); // <---- It calls `Derived::A()` and does job #2
```

But, if you write `A` in `B` with different parameter (overload it), you have to call it explicitly with actual arguments.

Comment: What exactly is a virtual function? I have read about it and tried to understand it but I'm having a hard time understanding what's the point of virtual functions